# Changing the image in Docker Compose based on the host OS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cross-platform

I am creating a PHP app, and using Docker + Docker Compose to run it.

My problem is, I want users to be able to run my project on any OS with no hassle. However, the official `mysql:latest` image is not supported on ARM processors (such as the Raspberry Pi), and so has to be switched out to `hypriot/rpi-mysql`.

Is it possible to do this either within one Compose file or with separate files for each platform? Or will users have to manually swap in a YML file when they clone the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your project into several YAML files, putting OS-independent stuff into one and dependent - into others. 
Your files will look like:

```
docker-compose.yml       -- common stuff lives here
docker-compose-x64.yml   -- lots of OS-dependent services for x64
docker-compose-arm.yml   -- lots of OS-dependent services for arm
```

Then you just need to launch this in following manner:

```
# for x64
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-x64.yml up ...
# for arm
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-arm.yml up ...
```

Comment: Note in more recent versions of docker can now build a single image that supports multiple CPUs, thus your docker-compose entry only needs to point to one image.    See https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/